# How to npm install all functions directories with AWS CodeBuild

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS Cloud Formation for my backend with the following project files structure:

```
| template.yaml
| lambda-functions
  | ---- function-1
       |----function.js
       |----package.json
  | ---- function-2
       |----function.js
       |----package.json
```

In the AWS buildspec I do `aws cloudformation package` followed by a `aws cloudformation deploy`.

If I want it to work, I need to do `npm install` on both `function-1` and `function-2` subfolders and commit `node_modules` subfolders to git repo.

How can I run npm install on all my subfolders directly from the buildspec so I don't have to commit node_modules subfolders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [lerna](https://lernajs.io/).

Lerna will also help you in case you have dependencies between your packages.

Basically you just have to add a lerna.json in your root directory and install your dependencies using lerna.

**lerna.json:**

```
{
  "lerna": "2.11.0",
  "packages": [
    "lambda-functions/*"
  ],
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

I assume you are using AWS CodeBuild, so here are some examples on how you could configure your install phase:

**buildspec.yml with lerna:**

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the install phase...
      - npm install --global lerna 
      - lerna bootstrap --concurrency=1 -- --production

  ...
```

`lerna bootstrap` will create `node_modules` for every single package.

If you don't want to use lerna, you could add one command for each package. Something like:

**buildspec.yml with yarn:**

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the install phase...
      - npm install --global yarn
      - yarn --cwd lambda-functions/function-1 --production install
      - yarn --cwd lambda-functions/function-2 --production install
      - yarn --cwd lambda-functions/function-3 --production install

  ...
```

or:

**buildspec.yml with npm:**

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the install phase...
      - cd lambda-functions/function-1 && npm install --production
      - cd lambda-functions/function-2 && npm install --production
      - cd lambda-functions/function-3 && npm install --production

  ...
```

Comment: Awesome I didn't know about lerna, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, from what I've gathered lerna uses symlinks (not re-installing the package) if it comes across a shared package, is that correct? If so, these lambda functions get packaged and deployed independently, how would that work? A symlinked package wouldn't exist.